# SQL Server: How to do an unmatched query using two SELECT statements

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, select, join

I have the following two queries that I want to combine and get mismatched results of the combination 'zone_type-building_type'

First SQL query

```
select zone_type, building_type from area where zone_type=2
```

Second SQL query

```
select zone_type, building_type from region where building_type='a'
```

I want to find out all of the 'zone type-building type' combinations that are in the first sql query but not in the second...and vice versa. Note that I'm looking for a combination of the two and not just separate zone or building types. For example if the zone type was 5 and building type was XYZ then i want to look for '5XYZ' that is in one query result but not in the other. Using MS SQL Server 2008

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution:

```
select zone_type, building_type from area where zone_type=2
except
select zone_type, building_type from region where building_type='a'
```

second query

```
select zone_type, building_type from region where building_type='a'
except
select zone_type, building_type from area where zone_type=2
```

Comment: this seems to be the solution however, is there anyway that both those queries can be combined in one statement? perhaps using "UNION"?

Comment: well when i use UNION then i get zero results...not sure why that is

Comment: (select zone_type, building_type from area where zone_type=2
except
select zone_type, building_type from region where building_type='a')
union
(select zone_type, building_type from region where building_type='a'
except
select zone_type, building_type from area where zone_type=2)